# Absorb value from NSNumber

Tags: swift, nsnumber

```
let Rating = self.currentPerson.Rating // This is a NSNumber

Rating -= 1
```

What I'm trying to do, is to take an `x value` from the `Rating`, and then print the `new value of Rating`.

**How do I do this properly?**

Comment: This doesn't compile: *binary operator '-=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'NSNumber' and 'Int'*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To perform this operation in the way you wish you need to write your own function for handling it:

```
infix operator -=

func -=(lhs:inout NSNumber, rhs:Double) {
    lhs = NSNumber(value: lhs.doubleValue - rhs)
}
```

You also need to use a variable rather than a constant in your implementation:

```
var Rating = self.currentPerson.Rating // This is a NSNumber

Rating -= 1
```

So that the value can be changed.